# Updating ASP.NET Label Upon Completion of Task

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok, so I've done some searching, but I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for. I'm fairly new to ASP.NET, but not to C#. I had to create a page to handle a regular web services request in order to update a web store with data from a web-based accounting software service. The problem I have is that I need the page to load first, then run the update, otherwise the page times out and the update fails. The display page has only a few labels, and that's all I require on it as the page will refresh every so often and run the update. However, I need the update method to be able to put the results to the screen. I have no problem getting the update to run, just making sure the results are displayed. I have no buttons that are pressed, there are no forms used.

Here's my page code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<div class="pageHeader">
    <div class="caption">
        <h1><asp:Localize ID="Caption" runat="server" Text="Update of Order Status From NetSuite Into AbleCommerce"></asp:Localize></h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label0" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

And here is my back code:

```
public partial class Template_Default : CommerceBuilder.Web.UI.AbleCommercePage
{
    private void PerformUpdate(object State)
    {
        Store _Store = StoreDataSource.Load(1);
        Token.Instance.InitStoreContext(_Store);
        String results = PontoonUpdate.soUpdate(); // method that performs the updates
        Label3.Text = "Update Completed. " + String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now + "\n\n" + results);
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label0.Text = "Update start time: " + String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);
        Label1.Text = "Order updates will begin.";
        Label2.Text = "Processing...";
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(PerformUpdate);
    }
}
```

I know I'm missing something, and I know it's due to my lack of experience with ASP.NET. If anyone has any pointers I'd be greatly appreciative.

---

Ok, I found the answer to what I wanted to do. I was searching for something else and found this...

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/implementing-waiting-pages-in-asp.net/

Comment: You need to learn about AJAX. ASP.NET just doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Do you think AJAX is the issue here? It looks like he just needs a callback method to set the label when the thread completes.

Comment: @JamesJohnson: You can't have a callback method like that in ASP.NET. It would be called after the page had completed processing, and no longer existed. He clearly doesn't want to hold up the page waiting for the thread to complete: he wants to update the display in the browser after the page has completed, and then after the thread has completed.

Comment: Michael, why are you updating on another thread? There are circumstances where threading can be useful in ASP.NET, but I don't see what the advantages are in this case. Can you explain why you're doing that so we can assist you?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: You can use multi-threading and callbacks in ASP.NET, but I agree that it doesn't make sense to do that here. This article gives an example similar to what I think Michael is trying to do: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38501/Multi-Threading-in-ASP-NET

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's my new link to explain async pages. However, I didn't see callbacks in there, in a quick scan. Can you show me where the article talks about callbacks?

Comment: The separate thread is something I've been utilizing in this project as the web services calls take some time to complete and before I started using them there were problems with timeouts occurring, especially during high traffic periods. If there's a better method I'm all for it. I just really need a way to be able to load the page and then run the web services calls after the page is loaded to avoid timeout issues. And then I need the last label to be able to be updated upon completion. I'll check out that link to codeproject.

Answer (score 1):

wrap your controls in an UpdatePanel. It is a poor man's AJAX. Place your controls (or your entire page for that matter) into the content template. Then in the Triggers section, tell it which controls to watch, and what events to catch. It'll do the rest. In your case, from here you just need some sort of event to trigger. It could be a javascript to fire a button onLoad, or even the bind event of some other control. It doesn't really matter.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="update">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="pageHeader">
            <div class="caption">
                <h1><asp:Localize ID="Caption" runat="server" Text="Update of Order Status From NetSuite Into AbleCommerce"></asp:Localize></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
                <asp:Label ID="Label0" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="generate" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```